# BugTrap and RapiDbg on Windows Mobile 6.0

Tags: debugging, windows-mobile, driver, pocketpc, outputdebugstring

I'm trying to port a driver and a few applications from a PDA running PocketPC 2003 (Windows CE 4.21) to one running Windows Mobile 6 (CE 5.2).

Does anybody know if/how I can log the OutputDebugString calls made by the driver, short of using the Platform Builder or any custom OS image?

Porting is 99% complete, but I need to troubleshoot and debug something that's happening at the driver level.

Until now, the combination of BugTrap (columbo) and RapiDbg allowed me to debug the driver without the need of the Platform Builder. I was able to capture all my `OutputDebugString`, pull them via activesync on my dev machine and work from there.

Apparently **bugtrap.exe** doesn't run on WM6 (it crashes) and I can't find any new version.

Is there a way to trap (dump to file, send to host via USB, ... whatever) the OutputDebugString calls WITHOUT the need of the Platform Builder or of a debug image of the OS?

I tried to use the tracetool framework (see sourceforge), replacing the ODS call (luckily all my debug statements use a macro) with its `Trace::Debug()->Send` and while regular DLLs and applications work as expected, the driver doesn't.